# AWS Cognito Fails when System Time is out of sync

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

AWS Cognito authentication fails if the system time is sufficiently out of sync.  Does anyone know why?

I've been trying to find some documentation on it but I'm coming up empty.

I'm using API Gateway auto-generated SDK's, authenticated through Cognito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behaviour of *all* API calls to AWS.

It is related to the `sigv4` signing method and is used to prevent replay attacks, where a previous request might be falsely re-sent.

Comment: I noticed it was used in sigv4.  Just interesting that its not documented anywhere especially when Cognito could be consumer facing.  People do still adjust their clocks as I'm finding out, and that causes problems because of this.  Are you aware of a way to tell cognito to use custom code for coming up with the datetime?

Comment: @CamHart how much out of sync (minutes/hours/days/years?), and what kind of errors can you find using the browser console?  The Javascript SDK has a [thing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Config.html#correctClockSkew-property) for that but I'm not sure exactly what it can/can't do or whether that's relevant, here.